# How to count distinct (x,y) pairs from a set of 3 dimensional tuples

Tags: python, set

I have a set which contains elements like

```py
(1,2,"r"), (1,2,"d"), (1,3,"p")
```

I am only interested in the number of distinct (x,y) pairs like in the above it will be 2. How do I 
calculate that using python?

Comment: Can you explain how the number of distinct pairs above is 2?

Comment: `(1,2)` and `(1,3)` are the two distinct pairs.

Comment: Does order of the x and y values matter with respect to distinctness?

Comment: yeah, the order matters. Think of it as coordinates with directions, and I am only interested in distinct positions without directions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a one-liner will suffice (supposing your set is a `list` of `tuples`, referenced by variable name `l`):

```py
l = [YOUR LIST OF TUPLES]
len(set([t[:2] for t in l]))
```

*NB*: the above treats the pair `(x,y)` as distinct from `(y,x)`; if `(x,y)` and `(y,x)` are intended to be treated as indistinct, then use:

```py
len(set([frozenset(t[:2]) for t in l]))
```

Comment: It'll be more prudent to fully understand what OP asking before giving an answer.

Comment: @DanielHao I think the OP's spec is sufficiently unambiguous; for completeness, I did add a second line which treats `(x,y)` and `(y,x)` as indistinct.

Comment: It is better with 2nd notes now.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. I am just waiting for some other alternative answers